# Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, activity, android-navigation-drawer

При создании приложения с *Navigation Drawer* мне необходимо переключение по *activity*, но никак не по фрагментам. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

Всё просто - в слушатель нажатия на элементы меню пишите:

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(context, ACTIVITY_NAME_CLASS.class));
```